# Sign up parse user on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website and I use Parse for connecting with users. The problem is that I don't manage to register the users. The error says: "mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create". Appreciate all help.

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Sign up</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   <form name="signup">
       Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
        Mail: <input type="text" name="mail"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Parse.initialize("app-id", "js-key");

        $("#signup").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault

        var name = document.signup.elements[0].value;
        var pass = document.signup.elements[1].value;
        var mail = document.signup.elements[2].value;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", name);
    user.set("password", pass);
    user.set("email", mail);

    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(user) {
          console.log("New user signed up successfully!")
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + "" + error.message);
      }
    });
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you using firefox? This error seems to be firebug related. Just checking.

Comment: Ok so the Chrome inspection was far more accurate.  file://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: you can't run ajax from `file://` protocol for browser security reasons. Try running that page on a localhost server

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
```

It should work then.

When your switching to a server environment, you can change it back to '//' in order to cover http and https.

Comment: this did fix the error I got in Chrome, but the users still won't show up in the Parse dashboard so they are not being created.

Comment: check the network tab in chrome, filter by XHR and see if there is an error.

Comment: Are you using Parse.initialize(appId, jsKey, masterKey) ?

Comment: in your parse settings -> keys, secrets -> show masterKey

Comment: NEVER expose your master key on client side.

Comment: Yes. Use this only for testing of course. Your masterkey should never be visible.

Comment: Oh yes, its event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2), the URL starting with `//` takes advantage of network path reference.

If your page is being loaded over `https`, the browser will try to bring in the script over `https`, and if over `http`, the browser brings it over `http`.

The problem is that you are opening this page from `file://` and not from a server.

So, the relative reference means browser tries to bring the script over `file:`, and it will, obviously, not find it. So it reports a 'not found' error.

Just specify the protocol (`http` or `https`) and it should work fine.

P.S: In comments of a different answer, I can see you are kind of exposing your master key, which is bad, very very bad.

`event.preventDefault` is a method and you should use the `()` to call it.

Comment: still won't help...browser will block the ajax requests needed to communicate with `parse`

Comment: @charlietfl If you are talking about `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` security restriction, then you should know that Parse servers have CORS enabled and you only need to call `Parse.initialize` before sending any data.

Comment: no...am talking about browsers block ajax when using `file://` protocol to load page.

Comment: @charlietfl Ah well I have used Parse over file protocol and never had problems. This  should work.

Comment: i find that very surprising unless you have modified your browser security settings perhaps? Or were not using a browser environment?